# How to count duplicated rows and then do a calculation based on the amount of duplicates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

For example I have a table like this:

```
Name            Grade
John Smith      3
John Smith      3
John Smith      3
```

So basically I want to count the duplicate row and to multiply that number by the grade to get a total grade.

In final it should looks like this:

```
Name            Grade
John Smith      9
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to list duplicates then:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM( grade ) AS total_grade
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY name
HAVING   COUNT(1) > 1
```

If you want to include unique rows then leave out the `HAVING` clause.

If there can be different grades for the same name and you only want to consider duplicates of both name and grade then:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( name, grade ) AS
SELECT 'John Smith', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Smith', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Smith', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Smith', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Smith', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John Smith', 1 FROM DUAL;

SELECT name,
       grade,
       COUNT(1) * grade AS total_grade
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY name, grade
HAVING   COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Would output:

```
NAME            GRADE TOTAL_GRADE
---------- ---------- -----------
John Smith          2           4 
John Smith          3           9
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called `group by`:

```
select name, sum(grade)
from t
group by name;
```